# Proper error messages on registering wcf client components in Castle Windsor

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle, wcffacility

I'm trying to get an error message when I try to register a component in Castle Windsor that points to WCF Service that has errors in the configuration. For registering the component I'm using:

```
container.Register(Component.For<MembershipService>().ImplementedBy<MembershipServiceClient>.LifeStyle.Transient);
```

The configuration file has the following two entries (bindings points to a non existing file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings configSource="Configs\local\nonexistingbindingfile.xml"/>
    <client configSource="Configs\local\system.serviceModel.client.xml"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

What happens is that Castle won't fail registering my component but it won't resolve MembershipService for any dependency of other components, it would set the property as null, but at this point I don't have any error logs that points to the file with the problem and troubleshooting becomes very hard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a valid instance is essential then I believe it should be done via Constructor injection rather than Property injection. This way Castle will throw if it can't resolve.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting the error message I was looking for. Using constructor injection will make the dependencies non-optional. Is there a way to make all dependencies resolved through property injection non-optional as well?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of Alex. This is the key difference between Property and Constructor injection.